# Using Bootstrap Glyphicons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons, icon-fonts

I am trying to use the glyphicons from twitter bootstrap. I want to use the pseudo-element :after instead of before.

.glyphicon.glyphicon-search:before
The above works just fine.

.glyphicon.glyphicon-search:after
The above does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you provide some of your code? I'd like to see how your using this in context.

Comment: Seems to work fine - http://jsfiddle.net/vrscy2hg/2/

Comment: Also check out the [**Manual**](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the glyphicon classes are only intended for use with :before and not :after. If you check out the source code in the CSS you'll see. An example would be:

```
.glyphicon-asterisk
```

the css for this looks as so:

```
.glyphicon-asterisk:before {content: "\2a";}
```

if it was like this:

```
.glyphicon-asterisk:before,
.glyphicon-asterisk:after {content: "\2a";}
```

you would be able to do your thing. You'll need to create a new class and add the content like this:

```
.glyphicon-asterisk:after {content: "\2a";}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is syntax issue. 
Try `.glyphicon.glyphicon-search::after` ？

Comment: Every browser that supports the double colon (::) CSS3 syntax also supports just the (:) syntax, but IE 8 only supports the single-colon, so for now, it's recommended to just use the single-colon for best browser support.

:: is the newer format indented to distinguish pseudo content from pseudo selectors. If you don't need IE 8 support, feel free to use the double-colon.

Comment: I can try the double colon but I don't think this is causing the issue.

.glyphicon.glyphicon-search:after {content: "/E###"};

.glyphicon.glyphicon-search:before {content: "/E###"};

The later works but not the first for some reason.

Comment: errr actually i am thinking maybe this is due to `;` . Try `.glyphicon.glyphicon-search:after {content: "/E###";}`. With the semicolon inside, since this is CSS, not JS. @user3259232

Comment: Sorry, the semi is actually inside.

Comment: @user3259232 mind creating a jsfiddle shows exactly how your code works?